# How do I order a SELECT query by the sum of a column on a related table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table of posts and a table of ratings. One post can have many ratings, and a rating can be any positive integer.

In SQL, how can I express a SELECT query that will return posts ordered by the sum of their ratings?

For reference, a sample schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Posts (
    id INT PRIMARY_KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Ratings (
    id INT PRIMARY_KEY,
    post_id INT REFERENCES Posts(id),
    rating INT 
);
```

Additionally, I only require posts, but that is mainly irrelevant.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Join the ratings to the posts, group by the posts to get the sum of the ratings and order by that sum. Without knowing the schema a more detailed answer isn't possible. So consider posting the schema as `CREATE TABLE` statements, possibly along with some sample data (as `INSERT INTO` statements) and the expected result with that sample data. Pleas edit the question to do so. Don't post it as comments because it is hard to read there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are unclear if you want posts with *no* ratings.  If so, use a `left join`:

```
select p.post, sum(r.rating)
from post p left join
     ratings r
     on p.post = r.post
group by p.post
order by sum(r.rating) desc;
```

(I assume you want the highest sums first; hence the `desc`.)

If you want only posts with ratings, no `join` is needed:

```
select r.post, sum(r.rating)
from ratings r
group by r.post
order by sum(r.rating) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    .headers on

create table posts ( 'posts' char(20)) ;
create table ratings ( posts char(20), 'rating' number) ;  
insert into post values ( 'post1') ;
insert into post values ( 'post2') ;
insert into post values ( 'post3') ;
insert into ratings values ( 'post1', 1 ) ;
insert into ratings values ( 'post1', 3 ) ;
insert into ratings values ( 'post1', 6 ) ;
insert into ratings values ( 'post2', 2 ) ;
insert into ratings values ( 'post2', 8 ) ;
insert into ratings values ( 'post3', 1 ) ;
insert into ratings values ( 'post3', 1 ) ;

select a.post , sum(b.rating) from post a
join ratings b on a.post = b.post
group by a.post
order by sum(b.rating) ;
```

output:

```
post|sum(b.rating)
post3|2
post1|10
post2|10
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 2 tables, a primary key and foreign key usage, and the fact that a post name may be re-used, I present the following:

```
   select p.post_name, sum(r.rating) as post_rating
     from posts p, ratings r
    where p.post = r.post
 group by r.post, p.post_name
 order by post_rating desc, post_name asc
```